# Transfer database to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, rails-postgresql

I am trying to transfer my database to Heroku but I with no luck. I followed all steps in this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and it says `Running`rake db:migrate`attached to terminal... up, run.8685`.

After I run `heroku open` I have access only to empty database and when I try to access some data, error shows: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms` `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method id for nil:NilClass):` So, there is no data present online.

What could be a problem? Thank you.

**EDIT1:**

When I go to a link `https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/my-database-name` I see this:

```
Statistics
Plan    Dev
Status  available
Data Size   6.6 MB
Tables  5
PG Version  9.2.5
Created October 22, 2013 16:45
```

It says there are 5 tables present and that's true. The problem is it seems these tables are empty. I don't see any option on Heroku website to browse database data. I checked with https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console, tried a couple of queries and database is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Did your migration successfully ended?? 
Were you able to saw tables in your database??
If there is problem in your migration try to load it from schema

```
rake db:schema:load
```

please check your database status from postgres.heroku.com

Comment: Migration successfully ended locally and when I run 'heroku run rake db:migrate' it says 'Runningrake db:migrateattached to terminal... up, run.8685.' It says only that, nothing else. I updated my post. It says there are 5 tables but it seems there is no data present.

Comment: rake db:migrate only make database it does not fill your database !!
If you want to move your data from local database or any other database then you need to make dump of your existing database 
`rake db:data:dump_dir dir="my_dir"`
and then load your heroku database with it
`heroku run rake db:data:load_dir dir='my_dir'`